# 'Node Api using mysql' deployed on heroku crashes after some time Interval

Tags: mysql, node.js, api, heroku, node-modules

I have created a Node API using MySQL and deployed it on Heroku. But after every 20-25 minutes it shows 'Application error' and I have to do 'Heroku restart' again to fetch data from API. My API calls work fine when runs on *localhost:port_no*

**Heroku Logs**

```
>2021-06-26T04:15:47.965652+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759660+00:00 app[web.1]: events.js:353
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759669+00:00 app[web.1]: throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759670+00:00 app[web.1]: ^
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759670+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759670+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759671+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:112:13)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759672+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759672+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759673+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.emit (events.js:388:22)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759673+00:00 app[web.1]: at endReadableNT (internal/streams/readable.js:1336:12)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759674+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759674+00:00 app[web.1]: Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759676+00:00 app[web.1]: at Connection._handleProtocolError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:423:8)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759677+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.emit (events.js:376:20)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759678+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol._delegateError (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:398:10)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759678+00:00 app[web.1]: at Protocol.end (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:116:8)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759679+00:00 app[web.1]: at Socket.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:94:28)
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759679+00:00 app[web.1]: [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759679+00:00 app[web.1]: at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21) {
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759680+00:00 app[web.1]: fatal: true,
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759680+00:00 app[web.1]: code: 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST'
2021-06-26T04:20:47.759681+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2021-06-26T04:20:47.817878+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2021-06-26T04:20:47.876488+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

**My connection.js file**

````
    const mysql = require('mysql');
    var sqlConnection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: ##,
        user:##,
        password: ##,
        database: ##,
        multipleStatements: true
    });
    
    
    sqlConnection.connect((err) => {
        if (!err) {
            console.log("Connected");
        } else {
            console.log("Connection Failed");
            
        }
    })
    
    
    
    module.exports = sqlConnection;

    ```
````

Comment: A connection is implicitly established by invoking a query - so you don't need the second part of your code: `sqlConnection.connect((err) => {` Provide some additional details on the following: how often does your API execute a query on average? were you using the `.end()` function in combination with `connect.()` and `.query()`? where is `mysql` running relative to your heroku app?